# Servers with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I'd like to test image loading over AJAX from jsFiddle, but I don't know any sites that allow AJAX from remote domains.

Comment: ...image *fetching* using POST? (For GET, no CORS would be used, right?)

Comment: @Arjan: I'm using GET. Still uses CORS. I still get the error, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, an image with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header:

http://novaember.com/img/testimg.php

Comment: ...and how long are you promising to keep that online? ;-)

Comment: I don't see why I should take it offline, so it's for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo! has an example URL for file *uploads*. Not sure how that would be used with GET though:

http://www.yswfblog.com/upload/simpleupload.php

See also [its usage in YUI3 examples](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/uploader/uploader-multiple.html).